# Why are these square shapes showing up on the side of the head when I sculpt?

Tags: mesh, sculpting, topology

[image][image: Weird voxel artifacts]
I found that shading it smooth with a higher sub surf worked better but then why would he be using it in the tutorial? It shows up perfectly smooth for him but when I do it, it just makes my object look way worse.

I'm following a tutorial on how to sculpt a face since I'm really awful with it and need to improve, but these lines keep showing up and making squares on the side of the head. In the tutorial he didn't seem to do anything special, yet his is perfectly smooth. I tried shading smooth, didn't work. Sub surf I doubt would work since the head already has upwards of 100,000 vertices due to increasing the voxel resolution.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hsy_42T4z70AtVc-kYiFmR9NwDTvEIzG/view?usp=sharing

This is the blender file, let me know if I messed anything up.

Comment: Those squares are faces, or what’s left of them. I recommend dropping remesh as it doesn’t seem to be helping right now.

Comment: Do you think it would be better if i just increased the sub surf modifier instead? To be honest I'm not sure why the guy in the tutorial didn't do that in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, i would think so. Or use dynotopo.

Comment: Alrighty, thank you! I'm not gonna lie I'm a bit frustrated right now. I looked back on the video, and I discovered that he SMOOTHED out the artifacts without even saying anything.  But that makes me wonder.  Is changing the sub surf better, or is his method the superior one? I just find it weird that changing the voxel size would mess up the object that much. Speaking of which, why does that happen anyway? Also, ignore the edit in my post, I discovered he smoothed out the squares when I was typing out this comment after I had saved the edit.

Comment: It's hard to guess how it happened, probably you had a low-poly object and you subdivided it in Edit mode but kept the Smoothness value at 0 in the Operator box, so it added topology but didn't smooth the whole shape. As for the question about how to do it, you can either subdivide or use dyntopo, you can also use both. Maybe use dyntopo only as it will only create additional topology on the parts that you're sculpting, while subdivide will add topology everywhere and thus make your object uselessly heavy

Comment: @moonboots That's exactly what happened. Thank you and TheLabCat for helping me out with this!